# Rails: undefined method `workshops_show' for #<#<Class:0x007f806c2b6760>:0x007f806c2b59c8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render a collection of workshops on my index page:

```
<%= render @workshops %>
```

_workshop.html_erb:

```
<%= link_to workshops_show(workshop.id) do %>
    stuff
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting the error

"undefined method `workshops_show' for #<#:0x007f806c2b59c8>"

Routes has:

```
 get 'workshops/show'
```

And when I rake routes, I see:

```
 workshops_show GET  /workshops/show(.:format)  workshops#show
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it ...

```
workshops_show_path # or workshops_show_url
```

You need to indicate whether or not you want the `_path` or `_url` helper to render the link.